# Error restoring SQL Server 2008 R2 database with TDE enabled to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, tde

I had a database with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) enabled in SQL Server 2008 R2. I can restore its backup successfully to another instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. However, when I restored to an instance of SQL Server 2014 SP2, the database was on "Recovery Pending" mode. Here are the error:

```
100 percent processed.
Processed 224 pages for database 'MyDatabase', file 'MyDatabaseBeta' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'MyDatabase', file 'MyDatabaseBeta_log' on file 1.
Converting database 'MyDatabase' from version 661 to the current version 782.
Database 'MyDatabase' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version 668.
Database 'MyDatabase' running the upgrade step from version 668 to version 669.
Msg 9001, Level 16, State 5, Line 52
The log for database 'MyDatabase' is not available. Check the event log for related error messages. Resolve any errors and restart the database.
Msg 3314, Level 16, State 3, Line 52
During undoing of a logged operation in database 'MyDatabase', an error occurred at log record ID (97:16:119). Typically, the specific failure is logged previously as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database or file from a backup, or repair the database.
Msg 3204, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
The backup or restore was aborted.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Msg 9001, Level 21, State 4, Line 52
The log for database 'MyDatabase' is not available. Check the event log for related error messages. Resolve any errors and restart the database.
Msg 3314, Level 21, State 5, Line 52
During undoing of a logged operation in database 'MyDatabase', an error occurred at log record ID (97:16:35). Typically, the specific failure is logged previously as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database or file from a backup, or repair the database.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 49
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Do you have any solution? I believe it is a bug in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Can you give us what the event log says about the underlying error ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to remove the TDE and restore to sql 2014 is good. 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/76141/